# Cookie is not setting in IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I am using this code to set cookie. It is working perfectly in Firefox. but not in IE9.

Below is the code:

```
HttpCookie visitorCookie = new HttpCookie("VisitorCity", DdlCity.SelectedItem.Text)
{Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)};
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(visitorCookie); // Add it to the header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when you want to set a cookie you should add it to the Response, not the Request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(visitorCookie);
```

It's the client browser, when sending subsequent the HTTP requests, that will attach the cookie as a request header.

Answer (score 2):

try adding your cookie to the HttpContext.Current.Response rather than the Request.

You can check the cookies from the Request object, but you need to set them in the Response

```
HttpCookie visitorCookie = new HttpCookie("VisitorCity", DdlCity.SelectedItem.Text)
{Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)};
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(visitorCookie); // Add it to the header
```

Comment: i solved the problem by changing request to response and go to=>Internet option=>advanced tab=> reset

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with IE. Discovered that the user had cookies disabled on their IE preferences. Check for that first !